# How to pass multiple parameters to selector function

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, selector

I have a subview , which has a selector

```
let subView1: CustomSubView = CustomSubView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0 , width: xx, height: yy))

    subView1.label.text = "Lorem Ipsum"
    cell.scroller.addSubview(subView1)
let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.subView1Action(_:)))
    subView1.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)

func subView1Action(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){
        print("Wow Subview1 is clicked")
    }
```

Now, I want to send the label text to the selector function. How Can I do it?
if I make the selector function like:

```
func subView1Action(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer , label:String){
        print(label)
    }
```

How should I call it??

Comment: You can also use the .tag property to pass something; so maybe a index to an array. You could also use your string as a reference to a Dictionary item you have loaded too! A couple of suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make the `UITapGestureRecognizer` the only function parameter. Then you can access the label with `sender.view as? UILabel`.

Comment: Unable to get the label.

Comment: it returns a nil value
actually, the subview is connected to a .xib file, which has  a label
so my subView has an IBOutlet of label

Comment: What about `sender.view` without the `as? UILabel`, what does it return?

Comment: it returns "(<Ultron_v2.ScrollerSubView: 0x7fa8c85a6b10; frame = (0 0; 200 60); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fa8c84bc990>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa8c85a5a40>>)"

Comment: Oh, I thought it was a `UILabel`. I'm not sure what a `ScrollerSubView` is, but I see `CustomSubView` in your code, so then `as? CustomSubView` should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the delegate callback signature.

But for your case, you can use `sender.view` to get back the UILabel.

```
func subView1Action(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){
    if let label = sender.view as? UILabel {
        print(label.text)
    }
}
```

Comment: it is returning a nil value

Answer (score 0):

You are getting it wrong.
When setting UITapGestureRecognizer an selector, the recognizer object will call the selector with only the "sender". So basically you can not add nothing to it.

If the string is a property of the tapped view you will have access to it from the recogniser, else you will have to pass it in other way.

```
func someAction(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){
    if let label = sender.view as? UILabel {
        print(label)
    }
}
```

Comment: It is returning a nil value